# How do I merge one git feature branch into another one?

Tags: git, git-merge, feature-branch

Our project has a Git `develop` branch and each developer is working on a specific feature branch that was created from that branch at some point.

So let's say I have the `feature1` branch and the `feature2` branch, and I need in `feature2` some changes that were made in `feature1`.

Is it ok to merge `feature1` into `develop` and then merge `develop` into `feature2`? What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure! If `feature1` were finished then you merge it into `develop`, then merge the latest `develop` into your branch, and then continue your work. Once it is done you merge your `feature2` into develop. That is the best way to do it, if you would try to merge `feature2` into `develop` without first merging the latest changes into your branch it is likely to be rejected because `develop` is ahead of your `feature2` branch.

If `feature1` is not yet finished, but you still need your changes that were made there you have 2 options:

1. branch off of `feature1`
2. Just merge `feature2` directly into `feature1`.